# In writing a purely relational prolog program, is it ok to use a carefully placed cut?

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut, clp

I am trying my hand in writing a relational prolog program that manages a key, value store. The initial code is taken from some lecture slides i found on the internet (http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/book/course.html -- see: using data structure slides).

```
newdic([]).
addkey(D0,K,I,D) :- D = [p(K,I)|D0].
delkey([],_,[]).
delkey([p(K,_)|D],K,D).
delkey([p(K0,I)|D0],K,[p(K0,I)|D]) :-
    dif(K, K0), delkey(D0,K,D).
```

This code allows adding more than one value with the same key -- which, is fine with me. However, it also adds the same key, value pair twice, e.g.

```
?- newdic(D), addkey(D, a, 1, D2), addkey(D2, a, 1, D3), lookup(D3, a, X).
D = [],
D2 = [p(a, 1)],
D3 = [p(a, 1), p(a, 1)],
X = 1
```

D3 includes p(a,1) twice.

To ensure that this doesn't happen i added the following code; and to ensure that backtracking doesn't find the alternative addkey clause, I added a cut in the end of the first clause.

Is this fair game for a purely relational program -- or are the better ways to ensure that no duplicate key,value pairs are added --without the use of a cut.

```
newdic([]).
addkey(D0,K,I,D0) :- lookup(D0, K, I), !.   % if the key already do nothing
addkey(D0,K,I,D) :- D = [p(K,I)|D0].
delkey([],_,[]).
delkey([p(K,_)|D],K,D).
delkey([p(K0,I)|D0],K,[p(K0,I)|D]) :-
    dif(K, K0), delkey(D0,K,D).
```

this leads to the following:

```
?- newdic(D), addkey(D, a, 1, D2), addkey(D2, a, 1, D3), lookup(D3, a, X).
D = [],
D2 = D3, D3 = [p(a, 1)],
X = 1.
```

No, more solutions are available -- the program returns immediately.

any suggestions are much appreciated,

Daniel

Note: as an aside: that if i add for the same key different values, the cut does allow to backtrack to identify the second value for the same key:

```
?- newdic(D), addkey(D, a, 1, D2), addkey(D2, a, 1, D3), addkey(D3, a, 2, D4), lookup(D4, a, X).
D = [],
D2 = D3, D3 = [p(a, 1)],
D4 = [p(a, 2), p(a, 1)],
X = 2 ;
D = [],
D2 = D3, D3 = [p(a, 1)],
D4 = [p(a, 2), p(a, 1)],
X = 1.
```

Comment: You could use something like `once(lookup(D0, K, I))` if you only want it to succeed one time.

Comment: Are you really happy with the current answers? After all, you ask something somewhat different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI Prolog has library predicates for dealing with key-value pairs and associations. I haven't looked at them closely to see what might match your situation, but something to consider.

If you want to roll your own solution, you could write `addkey/4` out recursively and maintain the relational behavior:

```
addkey([], K, V, [p(K,V)]).             % Add to empty dict
addkey([p(K,V)|T], K, _, [p(K,V)|T]).   % Don't add
addkey([p(K,V)|T], Kadd, Vadd, [p(K,V)|TK]) :-
    dif(Kadd, K),
    addkey(T, Kadd, Vadd, TK).
```

This implementation adds if the key is unique. It ignores the addition and yields the same dictionary back if you try the same key even with different a value (which is usually how a dictionary of key-value pairs behaves). You can enhance it for the uniqueness of the key-value pair pretty easily. Of course, the Prolog you're using would need to include `dif/2`, or you'd need to roll your own `dif/2`. :)

Comment: Thank you. 

I was interested in trying my own to get a handle on relational prolog; but now that you mention it, i will probably soon switch to using the assoc library in swi-prolog -- which is much more mature and likely more scalable as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if-then-else instead of cut:

```
addkey(D0,K,I,D0) :-
  ( lookup(D0, K, I) ->
    D = D0 % if the key already [exists] do nothing
  ; D = [p(K,I)|D0] ).
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. 

Does this if-then-else qualify as relational ...

Comment: @user2193970 The "if-then-else" is equivalent to using a cut and is no more "relational" in its behavior. The expression, `p1 -> p2 ; p3` behaves as: `(p1, !, p2) ; p3`. It may be visually more acceptable, but behaviorially is no more so. The relational version of an if-then-else is [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600).

Comment: Not only visually/aesthetically, it is also harder to misuse. Cuts are mostly used to avoid fixing problems with the logic.

Comment: I can't find if_/3 in swi-prolog -- can i write it out with other constructs?

Comment: @user2193970 unfortunately, `if_/3` isn't a standard predicate. It's defined in the link I provided.

Comment: I now have this code:

addkey(D0,K,I,D) :- 
 if_(lookup(D0, K, I), 
   D = D0,            % key already exists do nothing
     D = [p(K,I)|D0]).


i am getting an error with    call(If_1, T), which seems to add an additional parameter to the lookup/3, leading to the following error:

?- newdic(D), trace, addkey(D, a, 1, D2), addkey(D2, a, 1, D3), addkey(D3, a, 2, D4), lookup(D4, a, X).
ERROR: [... ]Undefined procedure: lookup/4
ERROR: [... ]   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR: [...]         lookup/3

Comment: Perhaps call/2 in swi-prolog and call/2 in iso-prolog behave differently, with the latter providing a return value and the former expecting another parameter.

Nope -- somehow the last parameter is understood as return value -- so not sure why the call/2 failed in this case.

Comment: You can edit the question instead of posting code in comments.